# Start and stop scheduling task in Spring java

Tags: java, spring, task, schedule

I develop a simple Spring Boot app that consumes REST and writes to DB.

I tried a `@Scheduled` annotation to initiate a task to run it periodically.
But the scheduling process starts automaticly, which is not exactly what I want.
I need an ability to start and stop a scheduled task from a web page.
When a user opens a page he must see a status of a process : Running/Stoped.

What is the easy way to implement it? Create a new thread? How to get a status of a process? Save it in db?

Maybe smb has an example of starting and stoping schedduled task from web page?

Comment: can you explain more and simple way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). For example, first of all create a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

then create a scheduled task:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> task = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
() -> System.out.println("some task"), 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and when you want to cancel the task, do the following:

```
task.cancel(true);
```

Comment: how can i display a task status on a web page in Spring MVC? I need to update a page dinamicaly depending on the task status (Running/Stoped).

Comment: @DenisSavrasov use method `task.isDone()` or `task.isCancel()` to check the task's status.

Comment: Thank you, i undestand this, the question is how to update status label on a page dynamically when task status changes. A task must notify a page that a process changes its status

Comment: The short answer is your page should periodically check the task's status (for example via ajax or similar approach) and refresh the status. Please create another question with details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402036/monitor-a-status-of-a-java-process-from-a-web-page